# Why chrome console is not returning undefined here?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Example 1:

```
var Hoist;
console.log(Hoist);
Hoist = "Variable is hoisted";
```

Example 2:

```
console.log(Hoist);
var Hoist = "Variable is hoisted";
```

I was expecting that console.log will print undefined for both the examples because of hoisting.
However, below are the outputs - 
[image]
[image]

As per my understanding in example 1,

Execution of Hoist = "Variable is hoisted"; is skipped during compilation step
and during interpretation step, value of Hoist is not available to console.log(); because assignment has not happened yet.

How console.log() gets the value in Example no. 1?

Comment: The Chrome console is notoriously weird; there are asynchronous aspects to the way it works.

Comment: You're mistaking return statements for console statements.

Comment: That assignment returns that string I think

Comment: `console.log()` prints `undefined` in both examples. Notice how both examples outputs two lines, the first is the `console.log()` while the second (with the left-pointing arrow) is the result of the last line which is just something the Devtools console does. In the first example, the last line is a statement and thus doesn’t produce an output while the last line in the second example is an expression which does produce an output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mistaking return statements for console statements.
In the images you provided, the right arrow shows your input, the line with no arrow is the result of the `console.log()` and the left arrow is the return value.

Both  of your examples log `undefined` as expected, however in addition to that, the first example has a return value of `undefined` and the second one has the string.

Comment: It’d be nice if your answer also included an explanation on why the first example doesn’t return anything while the second one does